# Qt Quick Checkbox inside ComboBox to create Surface3D series

Tags: qt, qml

I am using Qt qmlsurfacelayers example. I have added a comboBox with checkBoxs inside it. My plan is to use the check box status to add and remove Surface3Dseries. The idea is the "name" properties in ListElement will be the id of the Surface3Dseries and I can use addSeries/removeSeries to achieve my goal.

However `surfaceLayers.addSeries(name)` is not evaluated to `surfaceLayers.addSeries(layerOneSeries)` when I check the first box

```
        ComboBox {
        id: comboboxId
        width: parent.width / 2
        height: 50
        displayText: "Grids"
        model: surflist
        delegate: Item {
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            Row {
                spacing: 5
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 5
                CheckBox {
                    id: cahc
                    height: parent.height
                    width: height
                    checked: ischecked
                    onCheckedChanged: {
                        if(checked)
                        {
                            //here to load surface
                            surfaceLayers.addSeries(name);
                        }
                        else if (!checked){
                            console.log(name.visible)
                            surfaceLayers.removeSeries(name);
                        }

                    }
                }
                Label {
                    text: name
                    width: parent.width - cahc.width
                    height: parent.height
                    verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter
                    horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
                }
            }
        }
    }
    ListModel {
        id:surflist
                    ListElement { name: "layerOneSeries"; file: "red"; ischecked: true }
                    ListElement { name: "Two"; file: "green"; ischecked: false }
                    ListElement { name: "Three"; file: "blue"; ischecked: true }
                }
    Surface3DSeries {
        id: layerOneSeries
        flatShadingEnabled: false
        drawMode: Surface3DSeries.DrawSurface
        baseGradient: layerOneGradient
        ItemModelSurfaceDataProxy {
            itemModel: surfaceData.modelName
            rowRole: "longitude"
            columnRole: "latitude"
            yPosRole: "height"
        }
        //! [4]
        visible: true // bind to checkbox state
        //! [4]
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not working because you are passing the id of an object as a string, but you are really interested in passing a reference to the object itself. This is problematic for two reasons; ListModels cannot contain references to objects (e.g. id's), and secondarily because id's cannot be accessed via a string at runtime. You could accomplish this in other ways, though.

QML makes use of `objectName` which is a string that you can use to find objects.  One way to use this would be to iterate over grouped objects and identify them by an `objectName` match. I have created a simplified version of your code, which toggles the visibility of some rectangles to demonstrate:

[image: Checkboxes toggle colored rects]

```
Column {

    Repeater {
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { name: "layerOneSeries"; file: "red"; ischecked: true }
            ListElement { name: "two"; file: "green"; ischecked: false }
        }

        delegate: CheckBox {
            text: name
            checked: ischecked

            onCheckedChanged: {
                var object = getObject(name)
                if (checked) {
                    addSeries(object); // pass returned object by reference to addSeries()
                } else if (!checked) {
                    removeSeries(object);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Column {
        id: itemsContainer // arbitrary container to enable getObject() iteration

        Rectangle {
            objectName: "layerOneSeries" // objectName set to match string in ListElement, id not necessary in this example
            color: "red"
            height: 30
            width: 30
            visible: false
        }

        Rectangle {
            objectName: "two"
            color: "green"
            height: 30
            width: 30
            visible: false
        }
    }
}

function addSeries(object) {
    // as object was passed by reference, we can directly manipulate it
    object.visible = true
}

function removeSeries(object) {
    object.visible = false
}

function getObject (name) {
    // iterate over itemsContainer children to find and return the object with matching string objectName (not id)
    for (let i = 0; i < itemsContainer.children.length; i++) {
        if (itemsContainer.children[i].objectName === name) {
            return itemsContainer.children[i]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the child here referring to object parent or visual parent. Your code works but when I try to adopt to mine, the children is always 0. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I figured out why. Your code works if it is object. But I am dealing with Surface3DSeries which is a data series

Comment: I have to use seriesList to get the list of Surface3DSeries inside Surface3D. Still trying to figure out how to get a list of series that sits under Item.

Comment: To get data series under Item, I use resources.objectName. I think this is consider solved. Thanks very much for helping!